# Notification about iphone oriention

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to get notification when a user is rotate the screen to landscape or portrait,
it is possible?

I find couple of article but i didn't found answer for this.

Comment: do you need to get Push Notification or local notification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be notified when the device has been rotated you can either implement the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method in your view controller or you can register to receive the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`.

Before we start, the device orientation and the interface orientation can be different.  The device may be landscape but the interface may remain portrait depending on how the app has been written.  Device notifications are sent shortly before the interface orientation is changed to match the device orientation.  If you don't want the interface orientation to change you should implement the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method in your view controller to return `NO`.  This will stop the interface orientation being updated.

From your question it sounds like you want to receive notifications so I think you want to use the second method.  You can enable `UIDeviceOrientationChangeNotification`s using:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

There is a corresponding:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

You can register to receive the notifications in the normal way, using the `NSNotificationCenter` and registering to receive the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Finally, you would implement the method to be called when the notification is received as follows:

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotication *)notification {

    UIDeviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || 
        orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

        // Portrait

    } else {
        // Landscape
    }

}
```

As you can see, the orientation can be accessed using the  `orientation` instance method of `UIDevice`.

Comment: deviceOrientation != interfaceOrientation

Comment: @Jenox Good point! Do you think my answer needs to be clarified some more?

Comment: Yes, because the deviceOrientation change notification gets sent before the UI starts rotating (on the device), or even when the UI doesn't rotate at all because the active VC returns `NO`in `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`

Comment: The original question is about being notified of iPhone orientation, it doesn't mention interface orientation at all.

Comment: I have added a paragraph near the start to make the distinction between device orientation and interface orientation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add local notification in the landscape orientation in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method

try like this:

```
if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)

    {
         here schedule your local notification
    }
```